# pandas DataFrame.to_string() truncating strings from columns

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to use to_string to output a column from a `dataframe`, it truncates the output of the column.

```
print gtf_df.ix[:1][['transcript_id','attributes']].to_string(header=False,index=False)

Out: ' CUFF.1.1  gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "CUFF.1.1"; FPKM '

print gtf_df.ix[:1]['attributes'][0]

Out: 'gene_id "CUFF.1"; transcript_id "CUFF.1.1"; FPKM "1670303.8168650887"; frac "1.000000"; conf_lo "0.000000"; conf_hi "5010911.450595"; cov "9658.694354";'
```

Any ideas as to how to resolve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of attributes -- i.e. what do you get back from  type(gtf_df['attributes'][0]) --  If it is a string, can you tell us whether removing the quotes and semicolons solves the problem -- i.e. gtf_df.attributes = gtf_df.attributes.replace('\"','').replace(';','')

Comment: It is a string column. However, your recommended fix did not change anything. The answer presented below works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `__repr__` or `to_string` columns are by default truncated at 50 chars. In versions of Pandas older than 0.13.1, this can be controlled using `pandas.set_printoptions()`:

```
In [64]: df
Out[64]:
                                                   A    B
a  this is a very long string, longer than the defau  bar
b                                                foo  baz

In [65]: pandas.set_printoptions(max_colwidth=100)

In [66]: df
Out[66]:
                                                                      A    B
a  this is a very long string, longer than the default max_column width  bar
b                                                                   foo  baz
```

In more recent versions of Pandas, use this instead:

```
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
```

Comment: Thanks. That was definitely the problem.

Comment: As of now, Pandas version 0.13.1, the setting is of the form `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100`.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas changed how to set this option. Here is the [current documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/options.html)

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 100)
```

See the docs for other nice ones like:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 999)
```